# Android: Selector.select() returns 0 immediately

Tags: java, android, nio

I'm writing an Android app (>= 2.3) that connects to a server, and I have a problem with the NIO selector.

```
Selector selector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

selector.select();  // returns 0 immediately
```

According to the [Android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28%29),

> public abstract int select ()
>   This method does not return until at least one channel is ready, wakeup() is invoked or the calling thread is interrupted.

and the case falls into none of these but it returns. select() doesn't behave as described in the specifications and I think it's a bug.

**EDIT**

I've changed the code upon EJP's comment below:

```
socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
socketChannel.connect(serverAddress);

while (true) {
  selector.select();

  for (SelectionKey key: _selector.selectedKeys()) {
    if (key.isConnectable())
      finishConnect(key);
    ...
  }
  selector.selectedKeys().clear();
}
```

It works when the server is running: select() returns with 1 selected key, and I can call finishConnect() to establish the connection. But if the server is not running thus the connection is refused, select() returns 0 selected keys. If there's no selected key, there's no way I can determine what to do next. (and again, this case doesn't fall into one of the 3 categories when select() returns described in the API document.)

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the socket to something before you register it. Either do that before you put it into non-blocking mode, or else do so afterwards but register OP_CONNECT instead of OP_READ and call finishConnect() when it fires: if it returns true, deregister OP_CONNECT and register OP_READ.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if the server is down and the connection was refused? In such a case select() returns 0 and selectedKeys() are empty, so how do I know that the connection failed and deal with the situation?

Comment: The problem is that when the connection failed, select() returns without selectedKeys() set properly. Even if the connection fails, the key should be selected so that the consequent call to finishConnect() could catch an exception to know that it failed. That's the behavior of OP_CONNECT specified in the Java doc and it looks to me like a bug if Andoroid doesn't follow it.

Comment: You've missed the point. In the code above you are calling select *before* connecting the socket. That's back to front. isConnectable() occurs *after* you call connect(), and it is a signal that you should try calling finishConnect(). It isn't a signal that you may now call connect(). You don't need to wait for anything for that.

Comment: No I mean, I'd changed my code upon your suggestion and it works when the server is running, but if the connection was refused, select() still returns with 0 selected keys. I've updated the question.

Comment: Then you have a bug in Android. I've heard of NIO bugs there before, but I can't give you any chapter and verse. Note that your code is still incorrect: if `finishConnect()` returns false you must keep selecting; if it returns true you must deregister `OP_CONNECT`, and you may start using the channel for I/O; if it throws an exception you must close the channel.

Comment: My point is that it is a bug if it behaves differently from the way it's documented. select() shouldn't just return even if I misused it. If I had passed wrong arguments, it should've rather throw exceptions not just returning randomly. Or at least it should be documented like "if called with OP_READ when a connection has not been established, the behaviour is undefined" or something.

Comment: That's what I said. It's a bug.